# The handling of starting service from application and boot receiver

Tags: android, service

Scenario:
I start a service at boot time.
I want to start the same service at main activity manually.

I got 2 Questions:
1. How to ensure my manual service started is the same as the one at boot time.
2. how to retrieve those running services

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the Google documentation on boot services and interacting with services from your app? If so, please edit your question with specifics on the problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

> I start a service at boot time

Why?

> How to ensure my manual service started is the same as the one at boot time.

Use the same `Intent` structure.

> how to retrieve those running services

There is no such concept in Android. For starters, there will only ever be one copy of your service running. If the service is already started, and you call `startService()` again, it does not start up a second copy, but delivers the `Intent` to `onStartCommand()` of the running service instance.